# How to import two libraries with the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python there are two libraries that can be found on Pypi 'python-magic' and 'filemagic':

- https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/
- https://pypi.org/project/filemagic/

As can be seen from the documents, to import either one, the import statement is simply:

```
import magic
```

So how would you import both of these libraries in a project?

Comment: You need to rename one of them when you install it.

Comment: I played around with installing each package to a separate directory. (Example: `pip install -t your_virtual_env/lib/python3.9/site_packages/python_magic python-magic`) In theory, you could then use `from python_magic import magic as pmagic`.  This *seemed* to work for `python-magic` (though I don't have `libmagic` installed, so I got an error there. `filemagic`, however, appears to have a hard-coded reference to `magic` in its own source, so renaming that package is not so straightfoward.

Comment: `filemagic` appears to be the older of the two, and possibly does not use relative imports within itself.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use both of the libraries, you need to edit the packages.
For instance, I installed inside a virtualenv `python-magic`.  This created a directory `magic` inside `site-packages`.
Changing that name to `pymagic` and also changing every occurrence of `magic` to `pymagic` in the files `loader.py`, `compat.py` and `__init.py__` seems to solve the problem.
After that you can install `filemagic` and you can import the libraries as:

```
import pymagic #python-magic
import magic #filemagic
```

This solution is particular to these two packages.